# How do I use the SQL WHERE IN construct with PetaPoco?

Tags: orm, petapoco, npoco

I have a database table named Tags (Id, Name) from which I would like to select the ones where the name matches a name in a list. In SQL I would use something like:

```
Select * from Tags Where Name In ('Name1', 'Name2', 'xxx...)
```

But now using PetaPoco in an ASP.Net MVC3 project I'm stuck figuring out how to do it properly. So far I've tried:

```
var tagsToFind = new string[] { "SqlServer", "IIS" };
var sql = PetaPoco.Sql.Builder.Select("*").From("Tags").Where("Name in (@0)", tagsToFind);
var result = db.Query<Tag>(sql);
```

Which results in the following SQL, where **only the first** name in my list of tagsToFind is used to match the table data as opposed to all of them.

```
SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE (Name in (@0)) -> @0 [String] = "SqlServer"
```

It's a little frustrating, knowing this probably isn't so hard.. any help is appreciated!

**Update:**
I found out that it can be done in another way

```
var sql = PetaPoco.Sql.Builder.Append("Select * from tags Where Name IN (@0", tagNames[0]);
foreach (string tagName in tagNames.Where(x => x != tagNames[0])) {
    sql.Append(", @0", tagName);
}        
sql.Append(")");
var result = db.Query<Tag>(sql)
```

which gets me what I want while using sqlparameters. So I guess it's good enough for now, although not super pretty.

/Mike

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This will work except you can't use the @0 (ordinal) syntax. You must use named parameters, otherwise it thinks they are individual parameters.

```
var tagsToFind = new string[] { "SqlServer", "IIS" };
var sql = PetaPoco.Sql.Builder.Select("*").From("Tags").Where("Name in (@tags)", new { tags = tagsToFind });
var result = db.Query<Tag>(sql);
```

This will result in

```
select * from Tags where name in (@0, @1);
@0 = SqlServer, @1 = IIS
```

Comment: Great, that helped me with using multiple parameters in general with PetaPoco, thanks!

Comment: When I tried that with an integer array, it simply left the clause as "field in (@0)"

Instead, I performed a  string.Join(",", integerArray) as the parameter. This seemed more efficient anyway, as the PetaPoco ParametersHelper class iterates the enumerable element.

Comment: Holy smokes! That's some outside-the-box thinking

Comment: Version 4.01 of nPoco requires using .WhereSql() instead of .Where().

Answer (score 18):

Posting this for future seekers.  This works.

```
    public IEnumerable<Invoice> GetInvoicesByStatus(List<string> statuses)
    {
        return _database.Fetch<Invoice>(@"
            select *
            from Invoices                   
            where Status IN (@statuses)",
            new { statuses });
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use array class with Petapoco you can use this

```
string[] array = new string[] {"Name1","Name2" };

var foo = BasicRepository<Personnel>.Fetch("WHERE PersonnelId IN (@0)", array.ToArray());
```

Comment: That ``.ToArray()`` fixed the problem I was having. ``itemLists = rep.Find("WHERE ItemId IN (@0)", items.ToArray()).ToList()`` thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another sample:

**program.cs:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var db = new PetaPoco.Database("Northwind"))
    {
        var sql = "Select * from customers where Country in (@Countries)";
        var countries = new { @Countries = new string[] { "USA", "Mexico" } };
        var customers = db.Query<Customer>(sql, countries);
        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} from {2}", customer.CustomerID, customer.CompanyName, customer.Country);
        }
    }
}
```

**customer.cs:**

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

**App.config:**
(Connectionstring uses localdb connectionstring, so you might change it.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="Northwind"
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=northwind;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe, it's not a good way setting too many params in sql, [the max params limit is 2100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944276/how-do-i-use-the-sql-where-in-construct-with-petapoco/35868097#35868097).

> @Murat

```
string[] array = new string[] {"Name1","Name2" };
var foo = BasicRepository<Personnel>.Fetch("WHERE PersonnelId IN > (@0)", array.ToArray());
```

Constructing stander SQL in string, and check the LAST excute-sql, alway match your need.

```
var userIDs = from user in UserList select user.UserID;
db.Delete<User>("where UserID in (" + string.Join(",", userIDs) + ")");
```

Comment: Actually DON'T do this.  You have just introduced SQL Injection vulnerability by bypassing the SQL Parameters.

Comment: Use a Table Valued Parameter instead. Then you can pass the Datatable of IDs and not worry about hitting the parameters limit.