# dynamic Sql or sql algorithm

Tags: c#, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have 3 tables. The story is: I will choose materials. 
And which meals can be made with these ingredients.

And this is my c# codes.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmealmaterials WHERE ";
        string[] idler = textBox1.Text.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < idler.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < i; s++)
            {
                sql +="( materialId= "+ idler[s] + " and materialId= " + idler[i] +  " )" ;

                if (s<i)
                    sql += " or ";

            }
        }

        sql += " (";
        for (int i = 0; i < idler.Length; i++)
        {
            sql += " materialId="+ idler[i] ;
            if (i<idler.Length-1)
                sql += " and ";
        }
        sql += " )";                

        richTextBox1.Text = sql;
```

my tables:
[image]

my sql generator codes c#
[image]

Comment: and what is your question ?

Comment: i could not. thank you

Comment: What problem you are facing with the current code? Do you know what is the problem with the query which is currently generated?

Comment: @tuncgulec That's still not a question...  we have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Which meals are made with selected materials. 
I could not

Comment: what does "with selected materials" mean? must it use all of those and none others? all of those and possibly some others? at least 1 of those and possibly some others? at least some of those but nothing that isn't specified?

Comment: post sample data from your tables and also post the result you expect from your query

Comment: ultimately, this is an algo problem, not a coding one; first you need to figure out *what you need to do*; forget about code: how would you answer it if it were (say) pieces of paper in buckets?

Comment: Actually; I need to find out which dishes are made from selected materials.

Selected material Id: 1 -2 -3. Accordingly: 1,2,3 or 1,2 or 1,3.

Comment: Recipe A needs 1,2,3,4. Recipe B needs 1,2,4. Recipe C needs 1,2. Recipe D needs 1,2,3. The user enters 1,2,3 into your text box. Which recipes of those do you expect to see returned?

Comment: You understand. Thank you.

Comment: if input is 1,2,3 

1,2,3
1.2
1.3
2.3
Meals with

Comment: @mjwills yep just C and D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT b.MealID FROM 
(
SELECT mealid, COUNT(*) as IngredientCount FROM tblmealmaterials WHERE materialid in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY mealid
)
a
INNER JOIN tblmealmaterials b
ON a.mealID = b.mealID 
GROUP BY b.MealID
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(a.IngredientCount)
```

The above query will find meals that use *any* of the ingredients (with the `IN` clause), and then verify that the recipe *only* uses those ingredients (by comparing the `COUNT`s).

To avoid SQL injection issues (and to simplify writing the `IN` query), I'd recommend using parameterised queries via an ORM. [PetaPoco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944276/how-do-i-use-the-sql-where-in-construct-with-petapoco) provides nice `IN` support.

Comment: Thank you.  But :
"Column 'a.IngredientCount' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."